# How to reindent lines in IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

In Eclipse, I can select a few lines and press <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd> to reindent those lines. How do I do the same in IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm?

Note:

- I don't want to "indent" or "unindent" the selected lines - that would "move" the text to the right or to the left manually. I want the IDE to be clever about how to position the lines.
- I don't want to reformat anything, i.e. there should be no modifications to characters beyond the first non-whitespace character on every line.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`Code` | **Auto-Indent Lines** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Windows default keymap).

Comment: this works if you highlight the file(s) in the Project panel to mass change all the formatting -- auto-indenting lines in every selected file. note that you must select each file, not the folder.

Answer (score 18):

On a mac, it's <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Option`</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd> by default.

Comment: That's an I not an l.   As in aye, eye, not ell!  In case anyone was wondering :)

Comment: It's ⌘ + OPTION + L on mac!

Comment: ⌘ + OPTION + L  is Reformat code by default.  Ctrl + OPTION + I is reindent.  The difference between the two is whether you want to change line breaks, etc.  Of course, both can be re-mapped.

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me on mac was

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Windows:

`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L`

Mac:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This is what actually works for me as of today with default mappings

Answer (score 0):

In Webstorm the option can be found as "Reformat Code" in the keymap.
The default on Mac is <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>